# When connecting to a Wi-Fi network that doesn't offer any internet connectivity, what does Windows display in the network system tray icon?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking

When setting up certain Wi-Fi-based devices (for example wireless speakers/printers), the device in question creates its own wireless network that must be joined by a client to then configure the device. When connecting to a Wi-Fi network via Windows, when looking at the network icon in the system tray the connectivity status is displayed (for example, "SSIDName - internet access"). In the case of one of these Wi-Fi networks that doesn't actually offer an internet connection of its own, how does Windows display the connection status in this case - does it simply display the name of the network in question, along with "no internet access" or similar?

Answer (score 0):

SSIDName - No internet access + a yellow triangle in the bottom right of the wireless/lan symbol.

Answer (score 0):

The message is 'Connected, no internet'